# How to prevent url to show in web view

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

Hi there I am trying to create app where I am using web view to show my google drive folder but whenever internet got disconnect **in between loading the URL** at that a msg comes with **showing** the URL information.
What can I do to prevent **showing URL from users.**
Is it possible to show some other msg whenever internet goes down on starting or when it goes down on after starting loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a custom HTML page that will show if something wrong happened when loading the url.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        switch(errorCode){
            case ERROR_HOST_LOOKUP:
                webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"<YOUR OWN CUSTOM HTML PAGE TO SHOW WHEN THERE'S AN ERROR>", "text/html", "UTF-8",null);
                break;
            case ERROR_CONNECT:
                webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"<YOUR OWN CUSTOM HTML PAGE TO SHOW WHEN THERE'S AN ERROR>", "text/html", "UTF-8",null);
                break;
            case ...[IF YOU WANT TO CATCH MORE ERRORS]
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#onReceivedError(android.webkit.WebView,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Error Code Reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#ERROR_AUTHENTICATION

Comment: What kind of html page i can use have any example

Comment: something like these `<html><head></head><body><div><h2>No Internet Connection</h2><p>Please check your internet connection</p></div></body></html>`

Comment: hey if my html page is in assets folder then how to show that instead writing html here

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can either print the message or redirect the user to some other activity by checking the following method soon after the app gets launches...

```
    DD4YouConfig dd4YouConfig = new DD4YouConfig(context);

    if (dd4YouConfig.isInternetConnectivity()) {

    //redirect to webview
    }
   
    else 
    {
       //call alert dialog stating no internet
    }
```

This is a library function so obviously don't fail to add this line in Gradle

> ```
> implementation 'in.dd4you.appsconfig:appsconfig:1.3.3'
> ```